# How can i delete a specific name from my postgres array

Tags: arrays, postgresql, postgresql-12

Hello everyone I just started on working with postgreSQL and i was wondering if there is a simple solution to delete a single value from an array. In the screenshot im trying to delete a single name from my array.

my PostgreSQL version:
"PostgreSQL 12.4, compiled by Visual C++ build 1914, 64-bit"

[here is what im trying to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VhAXB.png)

Comment: Sample data is better presented as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DELETE` removes an entire row from your table.

You want to change the content of one column of an existing row in the table - for that you need to use `UPDATE`.

To remove a value from an array you the `array_remove()` [function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html):

```
update test
   set name = array_remove(name, 'Jan')
where 'Jan' = any(name)
```

The `where` clause makes sure that only rows are updated that actually contain the value `Jan` in the array.

Comment: hey i tried your code but it gave me an error which i do not really understand. Could you help me out. the error is as follows. 

ERROR:  operator does not exist: text[] ? unknown
LINE 3: where name ? 'Jan'
                   ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
SQL state: 42883
Character: 64

Comment: Ah, sorry. I used the wrong operator (only works on JSON arrays). See my update